# Disable Tmux from cycling through available layouts?

Tags: tmux

Is there a way to disable the Tmux "^b [spacebar]" keyboard shortcut that cycles through available layouts?  Often times I'll hit that keyboard combination by accident which screws up my tmux layout and results in much cursing on my part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is a way to disable any shortcut in tmux. You can see all shortcuts that you currently use by passing `prefix+?`. To disable shortcut add `unbind-key(alias: unbind) <key>` to your `tmux.conf`.

`echo "unbind Space" >> ~/.tmux.conf`

Don't forget to source updated tmux.conf(`tmux source-file ~/.tmux.conf`) or simply restart tmux.